# Google Closure - Form data to json object

Tags: javascript, json, forms, google-closure

Is it possible to get JSON from form data? I can get data map or string representation only.

```
var form = goog.dom.getElement('myform');
console.log(goog.dom.forms.getFormDataString(form));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply convert the map to JSON:

```
var json = goog.json.serialize(goog.dom.forms.getFormDataMap(form).toObject());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But why `.getFormDataMap(form)` returns values as arrays?

Comment: @Eugene: I updated my answer. I'm not sure whether `toObject()` is necessary though. `getFormDataMap` returns a `goog.structs.Map` which words like a hash map. Each key is assigned an array of values.